# How to you have a pre-set value in a textbox in thymeleaf?

Tags: html, thymeleaf

I have the below code snippet of a text box where one enters a mobile number. How do I have a pre-set value that a user can edit from?
For example:
The country code is already set and visible to the user, the user starts by entering their network provider number.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div th:class="transfer-label"> Mobile Number
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group transfer-field">
            <input th:id="msdn"
            class="custom-input-normal rounded-input hollow-input-light"
            type="text" name="msdn"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: By adding value="+1-" I guess

Answer (score 0):

you can populate input tag with value using `th:value` attribute.

`<input th:value="${variable}">` will render `<input value="variablecontent">`